# AngularJS $routeParams resolve and promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

So... I'm trying to learn some Angular stuff and then I reached a point where I'm stuck. In my app I'm using third party APIs so I cannot rely on `$http`, that's why you'll see `$apply` in the code.

So, basically I have this:

```
.when('/dashboard',{
  controller : 'DashboardController',
  templateUrl : 'ui/modules/dashboard/dashboard.html',
  resolve : {
    data : function(myService){
      return myService.start();
    }
  }
})
```

So far nothing really strange. That method supposedly have a promise, right? The start function is as follows:

```
var start = function(){
  return initializeConnection().then(function(){
    return login(false);
  });
};
```

So, basically, if everything works, all works. That's great. The thing is that, if I get promise rejection on the second function (that's `login`) I'm not able catch the error in this, which is my `AppController` which is created on top of the app (so it's always being instantiated):

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, previous, current, rejection) {
  console.log('Failing');
});
```

That's basically never called. A solution I tried that works, is to return a promise from the start function, then if any of those async functions fails, fail the returned promise. But as I see it, it should be unnecesary.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if you get promise rejection the `DashboardController` is never instantiated and your view is never loaded - so not much you can do there. You need to have a controller that will be instantiated even if your promise is rejected.

I think you could create a controller just to handle global events like `$routeChangeError`. I've created one below called `checkConnection` and it will be assigned to the root element of the app .

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/dashboard',{
      controller : 'DashboardController',
      templateUrl : 'ui/modules/dashboard/dashboard.html',
      resolve : {
        data : function(myService){
          return myService.start();
        }
      }
    })
});


myApp.controller('checkConnection', function ($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, previous, current, rejection) {
      console.log('Failing');
    });
});

myApp.controller('DashboardController', function($rootScope) {
    // code for your controller goes here
});
```

And in your index.html you will have:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="checkConnection">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

The controller `checkConnection` is going to be instantiated anyway - so you can rely on that to handle the error.

If no error happens then the specific controller (e.g: `DashboardController`) for the route you are accessing will be executed normally and your view will be loaded.

There are room for improvements but I think that could work for you.

Hope that helps or at least point you to the right direction.

Comment: Hi dluz, I forgot to mention that... I already have that code in AppController. Updating question

Comment: Hi Antonio, I did investigate it further and tried to replicate the issue you were having. Please take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18661324/1310945). It has 2 nested promises and if any of these promises fails the controllers still handles it.