# How to handle nested services and promises using resolve and $routeChangeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs

That's more like a research I did while I was playing with AngularJS and I would like to share as I think some people might find this useful.

Sometimes you need to fetch some data from several services before you instantiate the controller and render the view.

You could also have a situation when a particular service is waiting for a response from another service - kinda of nested service structure.

On top of that you want to make sure that if any of these services fails you will handle the error accordingly.

Comment: Ideally the question would look like something that a user actually asked.

Comment: I genuinely thought about that. And for most of the cases that applies. SO I decided to check the stackoverflow etiquette to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong. So I found this [link] http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17851. _The community benefits from having a growing store of useful question/answer articles on this site. This is true regardless of whether the question and answer are provided by two different people or the same person._

Comment: oh, absolutely! It's fine to provide question *and* answer! But even then, it would be preferable if the question where *phrased* as if an actual user was looking for the answer. In other words: it should be possible for others to answer your question as well! This also means that you should follow the normal guidelines for [tags-in-the-title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) and nice-but-unnecessary-phrases.

Comment: Ah, I see! Point taken, Joachim! :) I'm relatively new to StackOverflow. I will try to improve my wording. Thanks for your helpful feedback and useful links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module `myApp` has to services called `myFirstService` and `mySecondService`.

If you make any of the services fail by rejecting it:

```
defer.reject("second Service Failed");
```

The `$routeChangeError` event is fired and a message is displayed to the user in the console.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>myApp</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js">    </script>

  <script>

   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', 
         {
           controller: 'ViewCtrl',
           templateUrl: 'view/app.html',
           resolve: {
           loadData: function(myFirstService){
           return myFirstService.start();
         }
        }
      })
    });

   var appCtrl = myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope){
     $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, current, previous, rejection){

       console.log('Some service has failed: ', rejection);

     });
   });

   var viewCtrl = myApp.controller('ViewCtrl', function($scope, $route){

      $scope.feedback = {
        message: 'All the services are working!'
      }

    });

    myApp.factory('myFirstService', ['$q', '$timeout','mySecondService', function($q, $timeout, mySecondService) {
      var defer = $q.defer();

      return {

        start: function() {

          $timeout(function(){
            defer.resolve('FIRST Service \'myFirstService\' Failed');
          }, 2000);

          return mySecondService.start().then(function(){
           return defer.promise
       });

       }
     }
    }]);


    myApp.factory('mySecondService', ['$q', '$timeout', function($q, $timeout) {
      var defer = $q.defer();

      return {

        start: function() {

         $timeout(function(){
            defer.resolve("second Service Failed");
         }, 2000);

         return defer.promise;

       }
      }
    }]);

  </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

  <script id="view/app.html" type="text/ng-template">

    <h1>{{ feedback.message }}</h1>

  </script>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dluz : You just answered one of my questions a few minutes ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667388/change-attribute-from-within-directive).  So, I check you out and find you are pretty new to SO.  Then, I see you providing info like this.  Excellent stuff.  Thanks for posting and I don't care that you created a question just to show the answer.  This one helps me too.