# Change Attribute From within Directive

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS.  I have a directive that I want to have two way data binding.  The directive will have an attribute called "activate".  Initially, the value of "activate" will be "1".

The directive's link function will check if "activate" is equal to "1".  If so, it will change "activate" to 0, but do some other stuff.

Later, if I want the directive to do some stuff again, in the controller, I will change "activate" to "1" again.  Since the directive has the watch, it will repeat the cycle.

Unfortunately, every time I do this, I get "Expression '0' used with directive 'testDirective' is non-assignable!"  or "Non-assignable model expression: 1 (directive: testDirective)".

Here is HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <test-directive activate="1"></test-directive>    
</body>
```

Here is JS :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.directive('testDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            activate : '='
        },


        link: function( scope, elem, attrs, controller ) {
            var el = elem[0];

            var updateContent = function() {
                el.innerText = 'Activate=' + scope.activate;
            };

            updateContent();
            attrs.$observe( 'activate', function() {
                console.log('Activate=' + scope.activate);
                if( scope.activate == '1') {
                    scope.activate = '0'
                    updateContent();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here it is on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/justbn/mgSpY/3/

Why can't I change the value stored in the directive's attribute?  I'm using 2 way binding.

The docs say " If the parent scope property doesn't exist, it will throw a NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION exception."

NOTE: The update content properly shows the value of "activate".  However, the value of "activate" in "" does not update.

However that makes no sense to me as the parent scope property DOES exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although I agree with the use of `$watch` instead of `attrs.$observe` that's not the main reason for the error message you are getting.

The problem is that you are trying to assign a value to a non-assignable expression - as the error message tells you : `Non-assignable model expression: 1 (directive: testDirective)`

The non-assignable expression in this case is the number "1"

```
<test-directive activate="1">
```

You manage to pass the initial value (1) to the directive, but when the directive tries to update that value the attribute **activate** can't be changed - because it's a number.

So what you need to do is to change that to a variable, so you can update the value later.

See the code below where I initialise a variable in the $scope called activate.initialValue via a controller.

And I have also used `$watch` instead of `attrs.$observe`.

I've added the `$timeout` just to simulate an event to change the activate value after 2 seconds.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <test-directive activate="activate.initialValue"></test-directive>    
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.activate = {
        initialValue : 1
    }
});

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.activate = {
        initialValue : 2
    }
});

app.directive('testDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            activate : '='
        },      
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('activate', function(newValue, oldValue){
               console.log('activate has changed', newValue);
            });

             $timeout(function(){ 
                    scope.activate = 0;     
                }, 2000);
        },
        template: "{{activate}}"
    }
});
```

You can also see working here (http://jsfiddle.net/mgSpY/63/).

And here it is AngularJS official documentation about it (http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel:nonassign)

Comment: dluz : I had given the answer to Michael for a working solution.  But I just changed it to you.  You explained it so that I can understand it better.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Justin: happy to help! :)

Comment: This was part of the answer for me. I also had to run scope.$apply() after modifying it, or the $watch would not trigger.

Comment: I modified your directive slightly so there would be no need to explicitly call on `scope.$apply()`

Comment: You saved my day !

Answer (score 3):

To monitor a property of the scope, you should use `scope.$watch` instead of `attrs.$observe`:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
  var el = elem[0];

  var updateContent = function() {
    el.innerText = 'Activate=' + scope.activate;
  };

  scope.$watch('activate', function(value) {                               
    console.log('Activate=', value);
    if(value === 1) {
      scope.activate = '0'                    
    }
    updateContent();
  });
}
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgSpY/12/).

Notice that I've removed the `updateContent` call from the link function, because you can only safely access a property of the scope inside a `$watch` callback, unless you can ensure that the value bound to that property is available before the directive is processed by Angular.

`$observe`should only be used to observe/watch the value changes of a DOM attribute that contains interpolation (for instance, `value="{{ value }}"`). Check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-observers-and-watchers) to understand it better.

Comment: Michael : Thanks so much for the answer.  It definitely works properly now.  I don't exactly understand how using 'scope.activate=0' works now but did not before.  I'm still changing the value of the same attribute.

Comment: I'll update the answer with more information. Hopefully it'll clear things up.